# Do I need to create dummy variables to fit a seasonal model?

Tags: r, regression, lm

Per what I understood from the 2nd chapter of "Time series analysis" by Shumway. When doing a seasonal model in R, you may want to use a dummy variable to tell **lm()** that a given month value's should be used or not.

In the below example, in the **r** variable, I have a dataset with *Year*, *Month* and *TotN_conc*. (Monthly data for 14 years).

To fit a seasonal model I have done:

```
M2=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==2, 1, 0))
M3=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==3, 1, 0))
M4=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==4, 1, 0))
M5=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==5, 1, 0))
M6=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==6, 1, 0))
M7=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==7, 1, 0))
M8=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==8, 1, 0))
M9=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==9, 1, 0))
M10=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==10, 1, 0))
M11=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==11, 1, 0))
M12=as.numeric(ifelse(r$Month==12, 1, 0))

lm(TotN_conc~M2+M3+M4+M5+M6+M7+M8+M9+M10+M11+M12+seq(1,168,1), 
   data = r)
```

But I am getting the exact same result if I do:

```
lm(TotN_conc~Month+seq(1,168,1), data=r)
```

Should I just use the second approach? Why I don't need the dummy variables?

(screenshot getting same result below)
[image]

Comment: Let's back up here. If you have monthly data then it would be common in many fields to use 11 indicator (dummy) variables for 11 months to capture a seasonal effect.  In practice modern software lets you do that directly through factor variables (although the terminology and certainly the syntax may vary). But,, but, but: in many fields, usually but not always different, using sines and cosines is as good or better as an approach. Much depends on the data and the mechanism. Note that exactly how to use R is not directly on-topic here.

Comment: Here `TotN_conc` looks environmental to me and I would consider sines and cosines. But if the response is say industrial it could behave more like economic variables, with e.g. links to holiday (vacation) lay-offs etc.

Comment: @NickCox:  Am I right in thinking that, if we only wanted to capture the *shape of seasonality* or to forecast from the model, then we could choose either dummy coding or sine & cosine pairs to encode seasonality (with the latter option possibly being more efficient in terms of use of degrees of freedom). However, if we were really interested in making comparisons in the mean response among different months, then we would have no choice but to use dummy coding for Month.

Comment: @Isabella Ghement I think that's right. If particular months were the focus (e.g. a jump between November and December is expected) then sines and cosines don't especially help. Whimsically, the question is whether the process is in any sense aware of the calendar.

Comment: In this particular case, and many others, plotting coefficients against month is instructive. Furthermore, I would expect a logarithmic link to be a **much** better default for an environmental concentration than an identity link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that would be very clumsy. R is doing this automatically when you introduce the variable as factor:

```
lm(TotN_conc~ as.factor(Month), data=r)
```

But maybe you are getting exactly the same result because `Month` already is a factor - you can check with `class(r$Month)` - in that case, your specification like `lm(TotN_conc~ Month, data=r)` is enough.

You can also check with `model.matrix()` that R automatically constructed exactly what you wanted to construct with your dummy variables:

```
model <- lm(TotN_conc~ as.factor(Month), data=r) 
model.matrix(model)
```